# Need to target a Protractor element ng-repeat that has a filter

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a ng-repeat element that I would like to target which has a filter applied to it. The filter separates the element from other elements within the same repeating list.

[image]

```
ng-repeat="caseReferral in caseReferrals | caseByStateFilter:"accepted;need_specialist_reply;" as acceptedCases "`
```

I want to target the first of these in the list by

```
element(By.repeater('caseReferral in caseReferrals').row(0)).click()
```

How do I incorporate the filter into this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to approach it with a CSS selector:

```
$$('[ng-repeat^="caseReferral in caseReferrals | caseByStateFilter"]');
```

where `^=` means "starts with".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the part where the filter has to be equal to "accepted;need_specialist_reply;" ?

Comment: @JCC yeah, this is I'm not completely sure about. Are you sure you have it exactly like this in the HTML? Could you post the way the element looks in the HTML tree? Thanks.

Comment: Please see screenshot above.

Comment: thanks I figured it out. I ended up using $$('[ng-repeat^="caseReferral in caseReferrals | caseByStateFilter"]').get(0).$('td').click() which targeted a 'td' in my table row that had a listener which responds to clicks.